# Servlet container : how to forbid access to a folder

Tags: java, servlets

I use Jersey for my REST API. I use JSP files for the views. I put my JSP view files in `www/views/...`. Now I'd like to forbid access to these views through simple HTTP request on their canonical URL.

What is the best way to forbid direct access to these JSPs from the client ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stick the JSPs under `/WEB-INF` in the WAR.

Answer (score 1):

As johna has already said, if you put the .jsp files under WEB-INF this will prevent any access to them from the web directly.

If you want finer-grained security controls I would investigate a tool like [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) which will let you set up more complex security rules.